# Reset Ember Component on Load

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.Component that adds items to an empty array and returns the array on submission. The problem is, if I navigate away from the Route that contains the Component (both after submitting and without submitting), and then go back to it later, the information that was last in the array is still there. I would like to to be reset every time I navigate to the route with the component.

If this were a route, I'd simply write a `willTransition` or `deactivate` method to reset my attributes. But since it's a component, it doesn't have those methods, and I can't (that I know of) access the attribute I wish to reset from the parent route. So, how can I reset this array to be empty (or reset the the entire component) every time I load this route? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More likely than not, you're not setting the value you're using properly. Take these examples:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
    items: []
});

Ember.Component.extend({
    items: null,

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('items', []);
    }
});
```

In the first component, the same `items` array is shared by *every instance* of the component. So if you add an item, then create a new component, the new component still has the item (which I think is your problem).

In the second component, you can see that I set the `items` property in the `init` function. And when I set the property, I set it to a different array every time. Now, each component has their own `items` property.

It's hard to say without your code, but this seems like your issue.

Comment: yup, arrays are class properties, not instance properties.  Late initialization should fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!! I had no idea components even *had* any kind of init function, as I wasn't able to find documentation on this.

Comment: What if I have a new property tomorrow, I would have to add code to do this.set('newproperty', []);  is there no other way?

Comment: No, there's no other way. If you use any kind of object as the default value for a class property, that object is going to be shared amongst all instances of the class. Your only solution is to set it to a difference instance of the object for each component.

Comment: just to confirm, this means every instance of a component within the app lifecycle shares the properties?

Comment: It means that every instance of a component will share the _default value_ for properties.